# Assign value to getter

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have getter in the component

here is it

```
     public get canSave(): boolean {
    const isValid = this.rows.every(r => r.phoneControl.valid);

    if (!isValid) {
      return false;
    }

    const changes = this.managePhonesPopupService.getChanges(this.rows, this.params);
    return changes.phones.changed || changes.emergencyPhone.changed;
  }
```

Then in the method onSubmitClick I need to update value of it

Here is how I try to do this

```
    public onSubmitClick(): void {
    const changes = this.managePhonesPopupService.getChanges(this.rows, this.params);
    this.canSave = false;

    this.params
      .onSubmit(changes)
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.close(true).then();
      });
  }
```

But I get an error

> Cannot assign to 'canSave' because it is a read-only property.

How can I update the value of `canSave` in `onSubmitClick` method?

Here is complete code of a component

```
    export class ManagePhonesPopup extends DialogBaseComponent<Params, boolean> implements OnInit {
  public override params!: Params;

  public rows: IPhoneRow[] = [];

  public get canSave(): boolean {
    const isValid = this.rows.every(r => r.phoneControl.valid);

    if (!isValid) {
      return false;
    }

    const changes = this.managePhonesPopupService.getChanges(this.rows, this.params);
    return changes.phones.changed || changes.emergencyPhone.changed;
  }

  constructor(
    dialog: DialogRef,
    confirmDialog: ConfirmDialogService,
    private readonly managePhonesPopupService: ManagePhonesPopupService,
  ) {
    super(dialog, confirmDialog);
  }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initRows(this.params.phones, this.params.emergencyPhone);
  }

  public onAddClick(): void {
    const newRow = this.managePhonesPopupService.createRowControls('', false);
    this.rows.push(newRow);
  }

  public onDeleteClick(row: IPhoneRow): void {
    this.rows = this.rows.filter(r => r != row);
  }

  public onCloseClick(): void {
    this.close().then();
  }

  public onSubmitClick(): void {
    const changes = this.managePhonesPopupService.getChanges(this.rows, this.params);
    this.canSave = false;

    this.params
      .onSubmit(changes)
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.close(true).then();
      });
  }

  private initRows(phones: IEmployeeCellphone[], emergencyPhone?: string): void {
    const rows: IPhoneRow[] = phones.map(p => this.managePhonesPopupService.cellphoneToRowControls(p));

    if (!!emergencyPhone) {
      rows.push(this.managePhonesPopupService.emergencyPhoneToRowControls(emergencyPhone));
    }

    this.rows = rows;
  }
```

Comment: create a private property to store value that `canSave` depends on and then modify that value.

`private _canSave: boolean = false;`
update this in your `onsubmit()` 
`this._canSave = false;`

Comment: @BugHunter

but how I can mix it with logic that I already have in `canSave`?

Can you give it like code-answer?

Comment: Why are you trying to set canSave = false, when canSave is expressed by `this.rows.every(r => r.phoneControl.valid)`? I cannot quite imagine your use case for this logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, you are looking for a way to force the value returned by `canSave`.

To do so, you can add two additional private fields to your class:

```
  private _forcingCanSave = false;     // are we in a "forcing mode"?
  private _forcedCanSaveValue = false; // forced value to return
```

Then, modify your existing logic like this:

```js
  public get canSave(): boolean {
    if (this._forcingCanSave) return this._forcedCanSaveValue; // if in a "forcing mode", return the forced value; else continue with the existing logic

    const isValid = this.rows.every(r => r.phoneControl.valid);

    if (!isValid) {
      return false;
    }

    const changes = this.managePhonesPopupService.getChanges(this.rows, this.params);
    return changes.phones.changed || changes.emergencyPhone.changed;
  }
```

And in order to enable the "forcing mode", you can create a new method:

```js
  private forceCanSave(state: boolean) {
    this._forcingCanSave = true;
    this._forcedCanSaveValue = state;
  }
```

This will enable the value override in `canSave`. You can then use it like this:

```js
  public onSubmitClick(): void {
    const changes = this.managePhonesPopupService.getChanges(this.rows, this.params);
    this.forceCanSave(false); // force canSave to return false

    this.params
      .onSubmit(changes)
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.close(true).then();
      });
  }
```

Additionally, you can create a method to disable the "forcing mode", for example `stopForcingCanSave()` which will set `this._forcingCanSave = false;`. This will come in handy when you will want to stop forcing the value.

Comment: that's help. Thank's

Answer (score 0):

Create a private `_canSave` property and updates it within the `onSubmitClick` method.

```
export class ManagePhonesPopup extends DialogBaseComponent<Params, boolean> implements OnInit {
      public override params!: Params;
      public rows: IPhoneRow[] = [];
    
      private _canSave: boolean = false; // Private property for canSave
    
      public get canSave(): boolean {
        const isValid = this.rows.every(r => r.phoneControl.valid);
    if (this._canSave === false) {
      return false;
     }
        if (!isValid) {
          return false;
        }
    
        const changes = this.managePhonesPopupService.getChanges(this.rows, this.params);
        return this._canSave || changes.phones.changed || changes.emergencyPhone.changed;
      }
    
      constructor(
        dialog: DialogRef,
        confirmDialog: ConfirmDialogService,
        private readonly managePhonesPopupService: ManagePhonesPopupService,
      ) {
        super(dialog, confirmDialog);
      }
    
      public ngOnInit(): void {
        this.initRows(this.params.phones, this params.emergencyPhone);
      }
    
      public onAddClick(): void {
        const newRow = this.managePhonesPopupService.createRowControls('', false);
        this.rows.push(newRow);
      }
    
      public onDeleteClick(row: IPhoneRow): void {
        this.rows = this.rows.filter(r => r != row);
      }
    
      public onCloseClick(): void {
        this.close().then();
      }
    
      public onSubmitClick(): void {
        const changes = this.managePhonesPopupService.getChanges(this.rows, this.params);
        this._canSave = false; // Update the private property
    
        this.params
          .onSubmit(changes)
          .pipe(take(1))
          .subscribe(() => {
            this.close(true).then();
          });
      }
    
      private initRows(phones: IEmployeeCellphone[], emergencyPhone?: string): void {
        const rows: IPhoneRow[] = phones.map(p => this.managePhonesPopupService.cellphoneToRowControls(p));
    
        if (!!emergencyPhone) {
          rows.push(this.managePhonesPopupService.emergencyPhoneToRowControls(emergencyPhone));
        }
    
        this.rows = rows;
      }
    }
```

Comment: This won't work properly, because if we set `this._canSave = false;`, then `get canSave()` will skip this value and still return either `changes.phones.changed` or lastly `changes.emergencyPhone.changed`. Whereas OP wants to force returning `false`

Comment: Yes, youre right @SebastianKaczmarek

Comment: You're right; my response doesn't address of forcing canSave to return false when we set this._canSave = false;

Comment: now it should work properly by checking `if (this._canSave === false)`

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `canSave` is a getter function, which means it's a read-only property. But, you're trying to assign a value to it, which is not allowed.

Instead of assigning value to `canSave`, you should update the properties that `canSave` depends on. In your case, `canSave` depends on `this.rows` and `this.params`. Therefore, you should update these properties in your `onSubmitClick` method.

Example;

```
public onSubmitClick(): void {
 const changes = this.managePhonesPopupService.getChanges(this.rows, this.params);
 
 // Update the rows or params here
 // For example, if you want to set all rows as invalid, you can do:
 this.rows = this.rows.map(r => ({ ...r, phoneControl: { ...r.phoneControl, valid: false } }));

 this.params
   .onSubmit(changes)
   .pipe(take(1))
   .subscribe(() => {
     this.close(true).then();
   });
}
```

Updating `this.rows` to set all rows as invalid. You should replace this with the actual update you want to do.

*The key here is to update the properties that `canSave` depends on, not `canSave` itself.

Comment: rows- isn't form control